# Generating MySQL Reports on OpenOffice

Tags: mysql, openoffice.org

I don't know almost anything about this so if you have some experience let's share!

Thanks!!!

**sorry Matt:**

- OpenOffice 3.0
- MySQL 5.0.75
- Ubuntu 9.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Open office/MySQL and what Open Office application?

It looks like Open Office base ships with JDBC support - http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Connect_MySQL_and_Base

I assume that writer/calc etc also has this capability?